# Query involving 4 tables

Tags: sql-server

I'm stuck on an SQL query so I thought maybe an SQL MVP/GOD could find this here with small luck.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and here's a description of my tables:

**Tables - columns**

NodesCustomProperties - NodeID / NodeZone

Application - NodeID / ID

Component - ApplicationID / Name

CurrentComponentStatus: ApplicationID / Data

I'd like to fetch the SUM of CurrentComponentStatus.Data when Component.Name is like 'HTTP%: Bytes Transferred Between Proxy and Servers' for the same ApplicatioID and filter these results when NodesCustomProperties.NodeZone = 'one particular zone'

Research and testing have lead me here so far:

```
SELECT
  SUM(
    CASE
      WHEN [dbo].[APM_CurrentComponentStatus].StatisticData IS NOT NULL
      THEN [dbo].[APM_CurrentComponentStatus].StatisticData
      ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Data'
FROM
  [dbo].[APM_CurrentComponentStatus]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[APM_Application]
    ON [dbo].[APM_Application].ID = [dbo].[APM_CurrentComponentStatus].ApplicationID
WHERE
  [dbo].[APM_Application].NodeID IN (
    SELECT [dbo].[NodesCustomProperties].NodeID
    FROM [dbo].[NodesCustomProperties]
    WHERE [dbo].[NodesCustomProperties].NodeZone = 'one particular zone')
GROUP BY [dbo].[APM_CurrentComponentStatus].ApplicationID
HAVING [dbo].[APM_CurrentComponentStatus].ApplicationID
  IN (
    SELECT [dbo].[APM_Component].ApplicationID
    FROM [dbo].[APM_Component]
    WHERE [dbo].[APM_Component].Name LIKE 'HTTP%: Bytes Transferred Between Proxy and Servers')
```

This query actually works (Hooray !) but there's too few results so that's still not it. (Awwww !)

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I can't fix your query without some more information about data and expected results, but I can help you take some bulk out of your code. 1. Square brackets are only needed where the name contains a reserved character. All of yours can be safely removed. 2. HAVING clauses are only needed where you're trying to filter based on the results of an aggregate. What you've written will be fine in a WHERE clause. 3. Table names can be aliased in WHERE clauses and then referenced by the shorter alias - so dbo.APM_Application AS app and app.NodeID. Much less bulky code that way. HTH :-)